# AJAX POST sending blank space instead of JSON object

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm using a PHP file named register.php to register new users in my database with some of the data coming from the register form, however, the last two data fields on my database are meant to be two default JSON objects. To do so, I'm creating the variable in my js file on the register button click event and then using JSON.stringify() to send it with AJAX/JQuery as you can see down below:

Besides this AJAX/JQuery thing, I also tried to use xmlhttp, creating a request and sending the data with the open("GET", ...), send(...) and receiving it in the same way on the PHP file. Both ways end up receiving blank spaces instead of the JSON object.

```
    $("#registerButton").click(function(){

        cards = {"idcards": [1,4,7,10,13,16,17,19,23,27,29,35,39,41,43,46,58,77,95,120]};
        cardsJSON = JSON.stringify(cards);


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'php_includes/register.php',
            data: {cards: cardsJSON},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
...

$freecards = $_POST['cards'];
...

#I'm omitting the other query values to simplify this.

$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{$freecards}')";
```

I'm expecting to receive the same JSON object that I'm declaring in the beginning of the JS file and not the blank space I'm getting into the database.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: What is `registerButton`? Is the Ajax request the one that is actually running the PHP? Or is it cancled by a form submission that sends blank data?

Comment: @Quentin ```registerButton``` is an id of a button. The PHP file that runs AJAX is called index.php, which is where we have the register form. When the button ```registerButton``` is clicked, another PHP file is ran, which is called register.php, where we want to receive the cards data, so then we can send it to the database.

Comment: When testing your code and making `echo $query`, I get `INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{\"idcards\":[1,4,7,10,13,16,17,19,23,27,29,35,39,41,43,46,58,77,95,120]}')`. See it here: https://codepen.io/lipsumar/pen/qwPJJx

Comment: @Inês — Sounds like you are submitting the form, which is cancelling the Ajax.

Comment: @Quentin Then how can I get the data from both?

Comment: @Inês — Generally: By putting all the data in your form, having a single form processor script handle all of it (which could mean splitting it into two sets of data and calling two different functions), and not involving Ajax at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Get the values via the $_POST variable -**

JavaScript:

```
$("#registerButton").click(function(){

    var cardsObj = {"idcards": [1,4,7,10,13,16,17,19,23,27,29,35,39,41,43,46,58,77,95,120]};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType : "json",
        url: 'php_includes/register.php',
        data: {cards: cardsObj},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

PHP:

```
$jsonString = $_POST['cards'];
$cardsJsonString = json_encode($jsonString);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $cardsJsonString;
```

**Want to send a JSON from JavaScript to PHP:**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType : "json",
        url: 'php_includes/register.php',
        data: {cards: cardsObj},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents("php://input");
$phpObject = json_decode($jsonString);

$newJsonString = json_encode($phpObject);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $newJsonString;
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the value 'null' in string, but at least it's not the blank space. Do you have an ideia on why we're getting the 'null' string?

Comment: how you assign post data into variable?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `json_decode()` on `$freecards`.

```
$freecards = json_decode($freecards, true);
```

Comment: I keep getting the blank space even with ```json.decode()```

Comment: @Inês: u r not using success method in your ajax request

Comment: @Inês: in browser console? can u plz show your success method.

Comment: @devpro In the success method I do an ```alert(data)``` but it doesn't show due to the page being redirected.

Comment: "You need to use json_decode()" — That will convert it from a string into an array, but the OP is trying to insert it into a string.

Comment: @Inês - the page is redirected ? What do you mean exactly ? Does the page with the button reload or does `php_includes/register.php` redirects to another php script ?

Comment: @lipsumar when the button with the id ```registerButton``` is clicked, it executes ```register.php``` script. In that script, we collect all register data, and we want to receive a JSON object ```cards``` from the index.js file. But all we get is a blank space. After the ```register.php```file runs, if redirects to another page

Comment: @Inês: use `return false;` after your alert

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to JSON.stringify(cards). You can directly send **cards** instead of **cardsJSON**.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'php_includes/register.php',
            data: {cards: cards},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

Comment: "You don't need to JSON.stringify(cards)" — You do if you want `$_POST['cards']` to be a string.

Comment: I tried that as well, but it still doesn't send the JSON object.

Comment: @Quentin.. you will get it as JSON object as the question is about getting it as JSON not a string.

Comment: @PoojaMaurya — [There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). If you use JSON.stringify, you will get a string representation of a JSON text in `cards` which will then get passed to `$_POST['cards']`. If you don't use `JSON.stringify` you will have a JavaScript array, which jQuery will form urlencode as `cards[]=1&cards[]=4&etc` which PHP will decode into a PHP array in `$_POST['cards']`. It doesn't make sense to use an array in string interpolation as the OP is doing.  You **only** get JSON if you use `JSON.stringify`.